# UIActivityViewController appearing transparent in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am showing a `UIActivityViewController` after tapping a button. And, in any device with iOS7 the `activityViewController` is appearing transparent.

The project has Deployment target 7.0

And this is the code to open the `UIActivityViewController`

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"link"] applicationActivities:nil];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView =     self.buttonShare;
}
[activityViewController setValue:@"Subject" forKey:@"subject"];
activityViewController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

Any clues on what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that `self.buttonShare`is not nil when adding it as the sourceview?

Comment: Yep, buttonShare is being created through xib and is an IBOutlet. And,anyway, in iOS7 that line is not even called, that's just for iOS8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `view` of `UIActivityViewController` (`activityViewController.view`) before presentation.